# Reclaim disk space after deleting Outlook Emails

Tags: microsoft-outlook, disk-space

I have thousands of emails that I will be deleting from Outlook shortly. I am hoping to free some disk space after doing so. Will Outlook automatically release the memory used by emails after I delete them? To me it seems unlikely since Outlook stores its email in a single file. How can I get Outlook to release disk space after deleting a lot of email?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's easy. Just open **Account Settings**, follow the **Data Files** tab, double-click any PST file you want to compact and click **Compact Now** button on the Outlook Data File dialog.

Comment: For Outlook 2003 users, you can find this under File > Data File Management > Settings > Compact Now